# how to implement AJAX code into jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="demo"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Load Information</button>
<script>
function loadDoc() {
    var url = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bTVHJMcarm?indent=2";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("demo");
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var count = Object.keys(jsonObj).length;
            var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
            var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
            table.appendChild(tableBody);

            for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                var tr = document.createElement('TR');
                tableBody.appendChild(tr);
                var keytd = document.createElement('TD');
                keytd.width = '50';
                keytd.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Object.keys(jsonObj)[i]));
                var valuetd = document.createElement('TD');
                valuetd.appendChild(document.createTextNode((jsonObj)[i]));
                tr.appendChild(keytd);
                tr.appendChild(valuetd);
            }

            myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
        }
    };

    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i have written this code using AJAX for to get output of an json like

```
0   apple
1   orange
2   banana
3   strawberry
```

when i run this code i am getting same otput as i mentioned.
so how should i convert this code into jquery code to get the same output?

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bTVHJMcarm?indent=2");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>

Comment: from this code i m getting output like

Comment: {"0":"apple","1":"orange","2":"banana","3":"strawberry"}

Comment: but i want to see output like

Comment: 0   apple
1   orange
2   banana
3   strawberry

Comment: why do you need in such a way as you can get all fruit name by `variable[0]` will give `"apple"`...

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery equivalent of this code is to use `$.ajax` along with the unobtrusive `on()` event handler for the button. Within the `success` handler you can create the required elements and use the `text()` and `appendTo()` methods to create the HTML structure you require. Something like this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
     url: "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bTVHJMcarm?indent=2",
        success: function(json) {
            var $table = $('<table />').appendTo('#demo');
            for (var key in json) {
             var $tr = $('<tr />').appendTo($table);
                $('<td />').text(key).appendTo($tr);
                $('<td />').text(json[key]).appendTo($tr);
            }
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
<button type="button">Load Information</button>
```